# What version to use to learn linux developing?

Tags: linux

I want to learn linux developing. 
I develop for the last 8 years on visual studio (C++ / C# ) - and i want to setup some linux version on my machine and start to learn developing on linux.

What is the best ( and easy ) version that i can use ? 
Does there is any site or book that i can learn from ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer objectively. I can only give a suggestion of trying Ubuntu via VirtualBox so you can keep windows up and running at the same time. http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/#ubuntu1104

Comment: I'd recommend you start with Ubuntu - for ease, a huge community, a good package management with lots of packages. You can use different desktop environments, IDEs, kernels (if needed) etc. See http://www.ubuntu.com/

Comment: i dont need to have it with windows. i have new machine for it. i just need to make it easy to learn and start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be one of the latest [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu-nl.org/getubuntu/download) releases.